# VB.NET razor sintaxis

Tags: razor

I'm trying to use Telerik grid in my project and it's giving me an error with

```
  @using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
```

I don't know how to translate it into VB.NET.

Is razor the same for both languages?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for VB.NET is `@Imports Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI`.